# If $G \oplus H$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself, then must the same be true of one of $G$ and $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

> Let $G$ and $H$ are groups. If $G \oplus H$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself, then must the same be true of one of $G$ and $H$?

I found some examples of $G$ such that $G$ has no proper subgroup isomorphic to $G$.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ has no proper  subgroup isomorphic to each mother group.

(The reason: If $f:\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ is injective group homomorphism, then $f$ is also $\mathbb{Q}$-module homomorphism, so $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map. So, injectivity of $f$ implies surjectivity of $f$. This means $\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ has no isomorphic subgroup.)

I think there is counter-example of this claim but I can't choose one..

How to prove or take counter-example?

Comment: Thanks user1729! In fact, My question is if the direct sum of two group $G$ and $H$ is coHopfian, then at least one of $G$and $H$ is coHopfian.

Comment: Ooops, yes! I'll rephrase my comment as it is still vaguely relevant.

Comment: The key word is "coHopfian": G is coHopfian if no proper subgroup of G is isomorphic to G. You are essentially asking if the direct sum of two non-coHopfian groups is itself non-coHopfian. There is a recent paper which addresses the opposite direction (is direct sum of two coHopfian groups is itself coHopfian?): Goldsmith, Gong, Algebraic entropies, Hopficity and co-Hopficity of direct sums of Abelian groups. Topol. Algebra Appl. 3 (2015), no. 1, 75–85. The paper is about abelian groups, and implies that this "opposite" problem is open for abelian groups.

Comment: (Paper is open access. Find it [here](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/taa.2015.3.issue-1/taa-2015-0007/taa-2015-0007.pdf).)

Comment: @user1729 It's easy to see that the direct sum of two non-coHopfian groups is non-coHopfian (if $G$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup $G'<G$ and $H$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup $H'<H$, then $G\oplus H$ is isomorphic to the proper subgroup $G'\oplus H'<G\oplus H$). But isn't the question asking whether the direct sum of two coHopfian groups is coHopfian ("if $G\oplus H$ is not coHopfian, then must the same be true of at least one of $G$ and $H$?")?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, you are right. I must have got confused somewhere. So then the paper I link infact addresses the question in the OP, as does the paper [15] which they reference - this paper (Li, On the cohopficity of the direct product of cohopfian groups, Comm Algebra 2007) is paywalled for me, but its MathSciNet entry claims that the question in the OP is open.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an open question. Lets start by rewriting it. A group $G$ is called *coHopfian* if any injective endomorphism $G\to G$ is an isomorphism. Then the question asks:

> **Question.** Suppose $A$ and $B$ are coHopfian. Is $A\times B$ necessarily coHopfian?

(Thanks to Jeremy Rickard for correcting my interpretation of this problem in the comments.)

The paper Y. Li, *On the cohopficity of the direct product of cohopfian groups.* Comm. Algebra 35 (2007), no. 10, 3226–3235 [(doi)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00914030701410252), addresses this question. They write "The question was raised by Yongkuk Kim, and informed to the author by Professor Shicheng Wang", and they prove the following.

A group $G$ is *extremely noncommutative* if $[g, h]=1$ implies $\langle g, h\rangle$ is cyclic. For example, torsion-free hyperbolic groups are extremely noncommutative (so then "almost all" finitely presented groups satisfy this property).

**Theorem 1.**
Suppose both $A$ and $B$ are coHopfian groups. Then $A\times B$ is coHopfian if $A$ is either:

1. Extremely noncommutative and torsion free; or
2. Finite Abelian; or
3. Finite simple.

They also prove the following interesting result.

**Proposition 1.**
Let $A$ and $B$ be two coHopfian groups. If there does not exist nontrivial homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$, then $A\times B$ is coHopfian.

The paper B. Goldsmith and K. Gong, *Algebraic entropies, Hopficity and co-Hopficity of direct sums of Abelian groups*. Topol. Algebra Appl. 3 (2015), no. 1, 75–85 [(doi)](https://doi.org/10.1515/taa-2015-0007), also addresses this question. They improve on parts 2 & 3 of Theorem 1:

**Theorem 4.10.**
Suppose that $A$ is a coHopfian group and $B$ is a finite group, then $A\times B$ is coHopfian.

They also prove the following, which improves on part 2 of Theorem 1 in a different direction:

**Theorem 4.11.**
Suppose that $A$ is a coHopfian group and $B$ is a finitely co-generated Abelian group. Then $A\times B$ is coHopfian.

Comment: Really cohopficity? I would have expected cohopfianness or cohopfianity …  :)

Comment: @Hagen Yep! Although I had to double check - the word "Hopficity" seems to have first appeared in the 1960s and appears in lots of papers (59, according to zbmath), while "Hopfianity" and "Hopfianness" are much more recent and occur in only a few papers (3-4 papers and 2 papers, respectively).