# Direct sums of co-hopfian modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I recently saw this question [If $G \bigoplus H$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself, then must the same be true of one of $G$ and $H$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365309/if-g-bigoplus-h-is-isomorphic-to-a-proper-subgroup-of-itself-then-must-the-s), which turned out to apparently be an open problem. (There s a reference given in the comments.) We can ask a similar question about $R$-modules for $R$ not equal to $\mathbb{Z}$... a $R$-module is called "co-hopfian" if it is not isomorphic to a proper submodule of itself, so the question is whether a direct sum of two co-hopfian modules can be non-co-hopfian. Are there rings $\neq\mathbb{Z}$ over which the answer to this question turns out to be easier?

Comment: @JeremyRickard you're right, I have corrected it, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give a ring that answers the question, but I'll show that there is a ring with two co-Hopfian modules whose direct sum is not co-Hopfian. It wouldn't surprise me if somebody came up with an explicit example that makes this answer look a bit silly.

For the dual problem, whether the direct sum of two Hopfian abelian groups can be non-Hopfian, Corner produced an example in 1965:

*Corner, A. L. S.*, [**Three examples on Hopficity in torsion-free Abelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01904838), Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hung. 16, 303-310 (1965). [ZBL0145.03302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0145.03302).

Let $G$ and $H$ be the groups in Corner's example. There is a small abelian subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of the category of abelian groups that contains $G$ and $H$.

By the [Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem), there is a full exact embedding $F:\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to R\text{-Mod}$ of the opposite category of $\mathcal{C}$ into the module category of some ring $R$.

Then $F(G)$ and $F(H)$ are co-Hopfian $R$-modules, but $F(G\oplus H)$ is not co-Hopfian.